# Events callback onRest does not fire up with useSpring of react-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I want to use `react-flip-toolkit` to create an animation like [that](https://react-flip-toolkit.surge.sh/), but I am already using `react-spring` to bring some transitions to my page, so I want to switch from `animejs` to `react-spring` instead of both.

Following another codesandbox I create a small version just to test some things, you can see it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cardflipanimejs-jf246). Then I tried to switch (with this example) from `animejs` to `react-spring` and I created [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/cardflipreact-spring-xzo7e) codesandbox. It still not working as expected but I try to replicate this behavior in my webapp.

In my webapp I am unable also to fire up `onRest` event callback. I did:

```
const Card = ({ item }) => {
  const [spring, api] = useSpring(() => ({
    opacity: 1,
    transform: 'scale(1)',
  }));

  const onExit = (el, index, removeElement) => {
    console.log('onExit');

    api.start({
      opacity: 0,
      transform: 'scale(0.9)',
      onRest: () => { console.log('onRest'); },
  });

  return (
    <Flipped
      flipId={item.vizcartPath}
      stagger
      onExit={onExit}
    >
      <animated.div className="col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3 p-5 card-container" style={spring}>
        TEST
      </animated.div>
    </Flipped>
  );
};

const Container = () => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  
  return (
    <Flipper
      flipKey={searchQuery}
      decisionData={searchQuery}
      className="row"
    >
      {searchResults.map((item) => (
        <Card
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
        />
       ))}
    </Flipper>
  );
}
```

`searchQuery` is a string update with a form input, `searchResults` is array of objects with all items filtered by `searchQuery` content.

Am I doing something wrong with `onRest` callback? It is working on codesanbox and not in local and I already try to comment out all code not relevant.
I am using `gatsbyjs` in my webapp, could be something related to that?

Info:
**react**: 17.0.2.
**gatsby**: 3.4.0.
**react-spring**: 9.1.2
**react-flip-toolkit**: 7.0.13
**node**: 15.11.0